# HttpLoggingInterceptor Not Logging

Tags: android, interceptor, okhttp

I am running across weird behaviors with HttpLoggingInterceptor. I have noticed that if I use newBuilder() the logging does not work.

```
// instantiate object (in app)
val okHttpRequestManager: HttpRequestManager = OkHttpRequestManager(OkHttpClient(), null)

// execute request (in app)
okHttpRequestManager.execute(request, callback)


// another class (in request module)
open class OkHttpRequestManager(private val client: OkHttpClient,
                                 private val httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor?) : HttpRequestExecutor {


    override fun execute(httpRequest: HttpRequest, callback: HttpResponseCallback?) {

        if (httpLoggingInterceptor != null) {
            client.newBuilder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build()
        }

        // perform request below
        ...
    }
}
```

The above code snippet does not work. However, if I make my parameter a builder, everything works fine. Is using newBuilder() the incorrect way to do this?

```
// the below works
// another class (in request module)
open class OkHttpRequestManager(private val client: OkHttpClient.Builder,
                                 private val httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor?) : HttpRequestExecutor {


    override fun execute(httpRequest: HttpRequest, callback: HttpResponseCallback?) {

        if (httpLoggingInterceptor != null) {
            // no newBuilder() or build() and works like a charm
            client.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor) 
        }

        // perform request below
        ...
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea as to why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the method `newBuilder()` as the name implies, returns the new builder object and when you call `build()` on it, new instance of `OkHttpClient` will be returned created from the new builder.

Here is the source code:

```
/** Prepares the [request] to be executed at some point in the future. */
  override fun newCall(request: Request): Call {
    return RealCall.newRealCall(this, request, forWebSocket = false)
  }
```

`build()` method

```
fun build(): OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient(this)
```

> The newBuilder adds to the attributes of the existing client so you
>   will have a new client with both the old and new attributes.

If you want to use `newBuilder()` method then you need to make use of the newly created `OkHttpClient`.

```
// another class (in request module)
open class OkHttpRequestManager(private val client: OkHttpClient,
                                 private val httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor?) : HttpRequestExecutor {


    override fun execute(httpRequest: HttpRequest, callback: HttpResponseCallback?) {

        if (httpLoggingInterceptor != null) {
            val newClient = client.newBuilder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build()
        }

        // perform request below using newClient
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, the newBuilder adds to the attributes of the existing client, right? So I will have a new client with both the old and new attributes?

Comment: Absolutely Right! @portfoliobuilder